# Does DISABLE TRIGGER ALL on a table, also disables FK pointing at that table?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a PostrgeSQL database with tables that consist of huge amount of rows. I need to delete some information and to speed things up we plan to disable “FK constraints” on it

To sum it up my questions are;
If I disable ALL triggers on a single table, do they disable “FK constraints” pointing towards that table from another as well, or a should disable them separately?

Right now I just disable all triggers using this:

```
ALTER TABLE “table_name” DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

UPD: clarified my statement regarding FK, I meant “FK constraints”

Comment: Nope. Mb as it is my first time making a post I wrote I poorly. 

We read that “DISABLE TRIGGER ALL” disables also FK, as a part of other constraints. But the ultimate point is that I don’t know, if it disables FK pointing at that table. (I suppose the don’t)

Comment: Yes u are right. I meant not the FK by themselves, but the “FK constraints”. my error in explanation. I’ll update the post to reflect that, thanks

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Foreign key constraints are implemented with system triggers in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a foreign key constraint, PostgreSQL defines four system triggers:

- on the referencing table, there will be an `AFTER INSERT` and an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger
- on the referenced table, there will be an `AFTER UPDATE` and an `AFTER DELETE` trigger

So if you disable all triggers on the referenced table, you will be able to delete rows or modify key columns, even if that breaks referential integrity.